# Does OrientDB order by @rid in default?

Tags: orientdb

As the title, seem that OrientDB order result set of SELECT by @rid in default.

But I cannot find any document about this.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually it is so, orient order by @rid by default.

Comment: Thank you. It would be better if we have an official document for this.